# JPA getReference set a wrong id in my object (always set to zero)

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using the JPA `EntityManager.getReference(Class clazz, Integer pk)`.
I know that `pk` value is set to one but still, in the object returned by the method, the value is set to zero. I don't understand why.

Here's my code:

```
@Component
public class TypeDAO extends MainDAO {

    public TypeDTO simpleProxyRetrieveByIdType(int id){
        TypeDTO type = simpleProxyRetrieveById(TypeDTO.class, id);
        return type;
    }
}
```

My `MainDAO` class:

```
static protected <E> E simpleProxyRetrieveById(Class <E> clazz, Integer id) {
    EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
    E item = em.getReference(clazz, id);
    em.close();
    return item;
}
```

Here is the `TypeDTO` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "type_livr")
public class TypeDTO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "type_livraison_id")
    private int id;
        public int getId() {return id;}
        public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

    @Column(name = "code")
    private int code;
    public int getCode() {return code;}
    public void setCode(int code) {this.code = code;}

    @Column(name = "libelle_court")
    private String libelleCourt;
        public String getLibelleCourt() {return libelleCourt;}
        public void setLibelleCourt(String libelleCourt) {this.libelleCourt = libelleCourt;}

    @Column(name = "libelle_long")
    private String libelleLong;
        public String getLibelleLong() {return libelleLong;}
        public void setLibelleLong(String libelleLong) {this.libelleLong = libelleLong;}

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "type")
    private List<LivraisonDTO> typeLivr;
        public List<LivraisonDTO> getTypeLivr() {return typeLivr;}
        public void setTypeLivr(List<LivraisonDTO> typeLivr) {this.typeLivr = typeLivr;}

    public TypeDTO() {
    }

    public TypeDTO(int id, int code, String libelleCourt, String libelleLong) {
        this.id = id;
        this.code = code;
        this.libelleCourt = libelleCourt;
        this.libelleLong = libelleLong;
    }   
}
```

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in fact :

id is not really initialized to real id until you called the getId() getter.

You should have checked only in debugger !